# Is there a reason not to check in the virtualenv environment along with the source code of a python project?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I'm following the instructions for setting up to work with Python on a Mac
(http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/)

It suggests to store the virtual environment created by virtualenv in the project directory... which is of course a git repo.

Is there any reason *not* to add the virtualenv to the git repo?   It seems the natural thing to do, but ...

Comment: I believe virtualenvs typically depend on absolute pathes.

Comment: Where does it suggest to store the virtualenv in the project directory? I see no such suggestion, and that's a good thing, because even the most beign interpretation (have the virtualenv in the same directory as the `.git` directory, but not checking it in) is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: There's actually a quite difficult to understand sentence, which ends with "run the virtualenv utility in your project’s directory".  I can see, now, that I am probably misinterpretting this whole sentence :(  But I'm learning a lot from the answers to this question :)   However, if you run the command that follows this statement in the project's directory, you do end up with the virtual env in the repo...

Comment: Which is okay, though has downsides (have to add it to `.gitignore`, can't share the virtualenv across multiple projects, path to activate the virtualenv is longer, etc.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always try to check in the *source*, not the result of running a process.

A virtualenv is rather platform specific; a Windows virtualenv may require different binaries than one created on Linux. The paths in the script files will almost certainly use absolute paths, not relative paths, tying a virtualenv to a specific location on your harddisk.

Instead, check in instructions on how to recreate a virtualenv. Include the commands, and use tools like `pip`, [`zc.buildout`](http://www.buildout.org/) or [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/) to let others recreate the right environment *for their platform*.

`pip` lets you install packages into a virtualenv with a `requirements.txt` file. You'd commit *that* file. `zc.buildout` lets you define complex build configurations in `.cfg` files. Commit those. Pipenv tracks the top level dependencies in `Pipfile` and creates a `Pipenv.lock` file for perfectly reproducible environments, check in these two files, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Philosophically, the virtualenv isn't source code, it's a bunch of reproducible artifacts. It shouldn't be checked in, at most a script to re-create it more easily should be checked in.

Practically, a virtualenv is completely unportable even within a single system (can't move it without breaking stuff), much less across different systems with the same general set up (binary paths and ABIs might be different), let alone different operating systems (do I really have to explain this one?). So checking it in actually *costs* you time in virtually every case (because you can't use it after cloning the repository).

Answer (score 2):

Just describe the project's dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file and keep that versioned under git along with the project's code etc. It is easy to re-create the environment afterwards: just run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It's a really concise and clear way to manage a project's dependencies.

One reason not to keep the environment itself in the repo is that it will increase the repo's size significantly, which over time will make working with your git repo slow (especially cloning it).

There are many other reasons, of course...